# android - what does it mean to override packages?

Tags: android, android-studio

To be clear on what i am asking i will provide a real world example. take look [at this](https://support.hotline.io/support/solutions/articles/221188-hotline-android-sdk-integration-steps) and notice the following section:

> **Hotline - Android SDK Integration Steps** Modified on: Fri, 6 Oct, 2017 at 8:21 PM
>
> Integrate Hotline SDK (Using Gradle) Pre Requisites :
>
> 1. Hotline SDK clients require devices running Android 2.3 or higher
> 2. Hotline App Id and App Key from here: Where to find App ID and App Key
> 3. Android Studio and Gradle
>
> If you have any queries during the integration, please send it to us - Submit a Query
>
> **1. Add Hotline SDK to your app**
>
> Add the maven URL to the root build.gradle (project/build.gradle)
>
> ```
> allprojects {
>     repositories {
>         jcenter()
>         maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Add the following dependency to your app module's build.gradle file
>   (project/app/build.gradle):
>
> ```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>
> android {
> // ...
> }
>
> dependencies {
> // ...
>     compile 'com.github.freshdesk:hotline-android:1.2.+'
> }
> ```
>
> **1.1 Android target version supported**
>
> Hotline SDK supports apps targeting Android version 5.0+. The SDK
>   itself is compatible all the way down to Gingerbread (API Level 10).
>
> **When app targets Android 7.0+**
>
> When FileProvider is not configured for Hotline SDK, the following
>   error code is displayed
>
> ```
> "Missing/Bad FileProvider for Hotline. Camera capture will fail in devices running Nougat or later versions of OS (error code 354)"
> ```
>
> To fix this, please include the provider in the
>   AndroidManifest.xml as below and specify the authority in strings.xml.
>   Assuming, com.example.demoapp is the package name of your app, the
>   declaration would be
>
> **AndroidManifest.xml**
>
> ```
> <provider
>     android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
>     android:authorities="com.example.demoapp.provider"
>     android:exported="false"
>     android:grantUriPermissions="true">
>     <meta-data
>         android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
>         android:resource="@xml/hotline_file_provider_paths" />
> </provider>
> ```
>
> **Strings.xml**
>
> ```
> <string name="hotline_file_provider_authority">com.example.demoapp.provider</string>
> ```
>
> **When app targets Android 8.0+**
>
> When the app's target is Android 8.0 or later, and by extension  includes appcompat-v7 r26.0.0.+, you'll see the following errors
>
> ```
> E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/freshdesk/hotline/activity/InterstitialActivity;
> ```
>
> Hotline SDK's activities extends ActionBarActivity to keep the SDK
>   compatible with app's targeting older Android versions/appcompat-v7
>   revisions. It can be resolved by adding a proxy class
>   (ActionBarActivity was replaced by AppCompatActivity and was proxied
>   by lib itself since 24.2.0 of appcomapt-v7, until it was removed in
>   26.0.0) manually if you are building with support library 26.x.x.
>
> Add the following class in the appropriate package
>
> ```
> package android.support.v7.app;
>
> public class ActionBarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
> }
> ```

my question has nothing to do with Hotline. But after i did what they asked my package structure looks like this:

[image]

now that you have some background let me tell you what i dont understand. Does this mean that i am overriding any calls in package android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity ?  so does this mean that for any 3rd party build i have i can override its classes this way as long as i know the package and class name ?
Basically what does it mean to put package name of something i do not own into my package structure ? what does it do ?

**UPDATE**: look at this article here as [another example](https://medium.com/@_rpiel/how-to-test-facebook-connect-with-espresso-8a1af3e38d50) . if you read solution 3 you see we can do the same thing with facebook.login. i personally implemented this and it works.  my test package structure looks like this and it overrides facebooks loginCreator etc:

[image]

even though i implemented it, i still dont get whats happening. can someone explain ?

Comment: Basically those developers are stupid. They hide there implementation in a jar and they build their lib based on a outdated version of the support library. The solution is just a hack for fixing their incompetence. Just use a different library.

Comment: i added an update to the question with another real world example.